# SQL-SERVER-R2: Is there a 64 bit version of BIDS?

Tags: sql-server-2008, visual-studio

I need BIDS/VS to be able to recognize the 64 bit ODBC Data Provider for Oracle.  Right now it will only recognize the 32 bit ODBC Data Provider for Oraculous.

Answer (score 1):

BIDS is based on Visual Studio, which as of the current release is only available as a 32bit package.  When the SSIS package runs, it will run as a 64bit process (if launched by the 64bit version of DTEXEC.exe) but all the designing must be done within the 32bit environment.  This includes the current public CTP release of SQL Server "Denali" which uses Visual Studio 2008.

Comment: Denali uses 2010 IIRC ;) Or? ;)

Comment: SSMS for "Denali" is based on Visual Studio 2010.  BIDS is based on Visual Studio 2008.  When the next CTP is released that may all change.

Comment: SQL Server "Denali" CTP3 (which was released this morning) using VS 2010 for BIDS.